# Moment.js change the fromNow time range

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can I change the time range in moment.js for `fromNow()`, so the for hours range is from 60 seconds to 59 minutes and likewise for others not (90 sec - 45 mins).

[**ref: Moment.js Time from now**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Is there something similar to how you can change the lang:

```
moment.lang('en', {
  relativeTime: {
    future: 'Due in %s',
    past: '%s ago',
    s: 'seconds',
    m: 'a minute',
    mm: '%d minutes',
    h: 'an hour',
    hh: '%d hours',
    d: 'a day',
    dd: '%d days',
    M: 'a month',
    MM: '%d months',
    y: 'a year',
    yy: '%d years',
  },
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to do that easily: https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L934 (that's where it makes the substitutions). You'd probably have to write a function to manipulate the output from `fromNow`.

Comment: Requested for a future version [here](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/892).  In the meantime, you could modify the `relativeTime` function in your own copy of the source code.

Answer (score 4):

`duration.humanize` has thresholds which define when a unit is considered a minute, an hour and so on. For example, by default more than 45 seconds is considered a minute, more than 22 hours is considered a day and so on.

To change those cutoffs use `moment.relativeTimeThreshold(unit, limit)` where limit is one of `s`, `m`, `h`, `d`, `M`.

- `s`  seconds least number of seconds to be considered a minute
- `m`  minutes least number of minutes to be considered an hour
- `h`  hours   least number of hours to be considered a day
- `d`  days    least number of days to be considered a month
- `M`  months  least number of months to be considered a year

```js
  // Retrieve existing thresholds
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s');  // 45
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m');  // 45
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h');  // 22
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d');  // 26
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('M');  // 11

  // Set new thresholds
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 40);
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 40);
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 20);
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 25);
  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('M', 10);
```

**NOTE**: Retrieving thresholds was added in **2.8.1**.